# Mechanic shop with limited delay capacity

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, computational-complexity, np-complete

Suppose a mechanic shop serves $M$ customers for $N$ days. Each morning, each customer brings in a number of parts to repair (denoted by $0\leq A_{i,j}\leq A_{max}$).
Suppose all parts need to be repaired either on the day arrived or the next day. Also there is this constraint that each day parts of **no more than $W$ shops** can be delayed to the next day.
The objective is to maximize the minimum (non-zero) number of parts fixed in a single day for any customer.

The idea here is that sometimes the shop wants to delay parts of a customer to the next day deliberately because it knows that on the next day this customer only brings in a small number of parts. One example here is as follows:

$N=2,M=2,W=1, A_{1,1}=5,A_{2,1}=2,A_{1,2}=0,A_{2,2}=2$. It is clear that the shop should delay all of $A_{2,1}$ to the second day to join $A_{2,2}$. As a result, the minimum number of parts repaired for any flow in a single day is $4$.

Another example is $N=3,M=1,W=1,A_{1,1}=1,A_{1,2}=10,A_{1,3}=1$. In this case, the best way is to repair $0$ part in the first day and then $6$ each in the following two days. As a result, the minimum number of parts repaired for any flow in a single day is $6$.

For $W=M$ there is an efficient algorithm. This problem is quite hard when $W<M$. Even for $W=1$, or only a single customer's parts can be delayed each day, I feel it is still NP complete.

The decision version of the problem is: given $N,M,W$ and $A_{\dots}$ and a positive integer number $k$, determine if it is possible to schedule such that the minimum number of parts repaired for any flow in a single day is at least $k$.

I would appreciate suggestions on how to prove (or disprove) it is NP complete. In particular, the difficulty is what existing NP complete problem to use for reduction.